# Is there a way to flush out heap memory in java midway in processing a big list?

Tags: groovy, memory-management, heap-memory

For example, I am looping on a list that contains millions of entries and processing it in one thread, and in doing so creating one object on each entry.

```
//syntax is in groovy
List listToBeProcessed; // some injected list
List output = []
listToBeProcessed.each {
    new Output(it).save() //hibernate entity save
}
```

If I understand correctly. This will cause the memory usage to gradually go up until it finishes processing the thread, then the garbage collection will kick in as it release the reference

I was wondering if there is a way to maybe remove the references on the processed parts of the list as it continues to process the remaining entries?

Comment: One approach is, remove items from the list as soon as you are done (if you can) and use aggressive GC algorithm as garbage collection mechanism.

Comment: It would be more efficient to create these objects progressively either using a parallel stream or a queue.  This way there is not so many object in use at any one time. i.e. don't load them all into the list in the first place.

Comment: Do you need them all in memory at once?  Or can you change them and send them on one at a time?

Comment: Also, `collect` would be quicker than the above, as it pre-allocates the returned list

Comment: the main reason it was in one list is because, if one entry of the list is "bad", then we have to abort or cancel processing the whole list.

Comment: @tim_yates I have rephrased the code snippet to reflect better my current situation.